# Angularjs route doesn't works without # in URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, routes

I have a problem with my angularjs routes. My simplified route config looks like:

```
App.config([ '$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider ) {

$routeProvider.
  when('/', {  
      redirectTo: '/home'
  }).
  when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  }).
  when('/404', {   
      templateUrl: '404.html'
  }).
  when('/500', {   
      templateUrl: '500.html'
  }).
  when('/:tabName', {   
      templateUrl: 'tabView.html',
      controller: 'TabContentCtrl'
  }).
  when('/:tabName/:widgetName', {    
      templateUrl: 'tabView.html',
      controller: 'TabContentCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({                    
      redirectTo: '/404'
  });
}]);
```

The problem is when I put URLs http://myapp or http://myapp/ into browser, it redirects me nowhere, nothing takes place, even redirect to 404 error page. It starts working when I put hash to URL http://myapp/#, then it works as I expected. But why my default route for root URL of application http://myapp, and http://myapp/ did not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to enable html5mode:

**config javascript**

```
App.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how have you set your virtual host and is it pointing to your root index.html? If yes, then if you type http://myapp it would definitely take you to http://myapp/#/home